# Angular CLI removing prefixed CSS

Tags: angular, flexbox, webkit, angular-cli, postcss

I'm using `@angular/cli@1.4.3`.

Before building, i'm using gulp-postcss to autoprefix my CSS. It works a treat. Here's a sample of the CSS it creates (not minified for readability):

```css
form.registration-form {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Perfect! But when the CLI builds the app, the CSS created looks like this:

```css
form.registration-form {
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    align-items:center;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -ms-flex-positive:1;
    flex-grow:1;
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap
}
```

Notice how HALF of it is missing!? :/

I'm baffled, any help and I'll be eternally grateful!

Cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Angular cli's autoprefixer is using browserslist (https://github.com/ai/browserslist) to determine what prefixes you need in your css. You can add a browserslist property to your package.json file for browserslist to pick up what browsers you want to support

```
"browserslist": [
   "> 1%",
   "last 2 versions"
]
```

or you an add a .browserslistrc file to the root of your directory

```
### Supported Browsers

> 1%
last 2 versions
```

Now autoprefixer will pick up what browsers you want to support and prefix accordingly. This is all outined in the angular cli doc (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-autoprefixer)

In short, gulp-postcss & angular cli are supporting a different range of browsers, which results in the different css prefixes.

Comment: For anybody else looking into this, I was almost able to completely remove my reliance on gulp throughout my whole project with this knowledge. I knew the CLI used webpack but didn't know it was configured to autoprefix CSS like this. Eternal gratitude is yours LLai <3